# With WebStorm, How to get React Auto-Import component to work on HOC

Tags: reactjs, webstorm

I love that in WebStorm, I can Insert a component into a JavaScript file and it automatically takes care of the import for me.  I've created an HOC that expoerts as is typical and looks like this:

```
const Speakershoc = ({data, isLoading, error}) => {
    ...
}
export default withFetching(API + DEFAULT_QUERY)(Speakershoc);
```

In my other React component where I want to include this, I insert it by typing

```
<Speakershoc />
```

But WebStorm does not know it's a component and does not make the insert for me.  Is there a way to tell webstorm (give it a hint) that it should include my HOC for me?

EDIT - SOLUTION THAT SEEMS TO WORK AS SUGGESTED BY @skyboyer

```
export const Speakershoc = withFetching(API + DEFAULT_QUERY)(Speakershoc);
```

Comment: I believe root cause is using default export vs named export. try export as named one.

Comment: Thanks @skyboyer  Are you suggesting what I put above as a proposed solution? Is that a reasonable pattern to follow for HOC's? Seems a little bulkly, but then the export itself feels bulky already.

Comment: By now I cannot verify if it works. But if it works I believe it's worth it having `import`/`export` slightly more verbose for getting benefits in productivity because of 'automatic import injection'. Anyway whenever you have default export or named one it does not affect HOC concept in any way

Comment: [offtopic for current question] btw for better testability and re-usability it makes sense to export both: original component and one wrapped with HOC(s).